# Having a recurring issue with MySQL and Pyt- at bottom of screen when running my scripts

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database

I have been wrestling with this issue and i can't figure it out nor do i expect to given my limited experience. It is part of my login_portal which is attached to a database on MySQL and everything works well except i have that recurring message when running.
I have placed pass, Exception and ValueException in the except blocks still with the same result...
Which given the semantics of the TypeError message just does not compute i feel i have satisfied the problem three-fold.

The error i keep getting at the bottom when running my scripts is below-

**Exception ignored in: <function BaseMySQLSocket.**del** at 0x000001A7375131F0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 149, in **del**
File "C:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 137, in shutdown
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed**

I am sure "create_db_connection" is my problem function:

```
# Functions
def create_db_connection(host_name, user_name, pass_word, db_name):
    connection = None
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=host_name,
            user=user_name,
            passwd=pass_word,
            database=db_name
        )
        print("MySQL Database connection successful")
    except Error as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")

def read_query(connection, query):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    result = None
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        return result
    except Error as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")

# My calls
connection = create_db_connection('localhost', 'root', 'GeoPlayingCode17##',
                                  'login_details')
results = read_query(connection, q1)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to catch an exception that is not from the BaseException. Thats where exceptions are defined.
Try this

```
try:
    Do_something()
except Exception as Ex:
    print(Ex)
```

This must sort it out

Comment: I amended all the except clauses with that and still have the same TypeError occurring.

Comment: You can't catch Error as Error is not an Exception.  Replace Error with the exception you are trying to catch. Like for eg: EOFError, ZeroDivisionError etc

Comment: Try replacing Error with mysql.connector.Error